# Error OpenOCD debugging on ATSAMA5D36 Xplained board:

Tags: atmel, ftdi, openocd, jtag

- I'm trying to flash on ATSAMA5D36 Xplained board using OpenOCD.
- I builded and compiled application and want to debug using OpenOCD. When I am doing that I get the following error.

**Openocd verson:**

> openocd-0.9.0.tar.gz

```
 root@Harsha:/home/harsha/openocd_bin# openocd -f 

interface/ftdi/ngxtech.cfg -f target/sama5d36.cfg Open On-Chip Debugger 0.10.0+dev-00556-gd0be163-dirty (2018-10-25-18:04) Licensed under GNU GPL v2
```

For bug reports, read http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html WARNING!

```
 This file was not tested with real interface, but is assumed to work as this
interface uses the same layout as configs that were verified. Please report your
experience with this file to openocd-devel mailing list, so it could be marked
as working or fixed.
trst_and_srst separate srst_gates_jtag trst_push_pull srst_open_drain 
connect_deassert_srst
adapter speed: 1500 kHz
Info : auto-selecting first available session transport "jtag". To override use 'transport select <transport>'.
embedded:startup.tcl:21: Error: target requires -dap parameter instead of -chain-position!
in procedure 'script' 
at file "embedded:startup.tcl", line 60
in procedure 'target' called at file "target/sama5d36.cfg", line 46
in procedure 'ocd_bouncer' 
at file "embedded:startup.tcl", line 21
```

**Steps Followed:**

```
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential
$ sudo apt-get install automake
$ sudo apt-get install autoconf
$ sudo apt-get install texinfo
```

**Build:**

```
$ cd openocd-r520/
$ ./bootstrap
$ ./configure  --enable-ft2232_ftd2xx
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

*I'm using a JTAG adapter based on the FT2232 chip, FTDI support library.*

```
$ wget http://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/D2XX/Linux/libftd2xx0.20.0 .tar.gz
$ tar -zxf libftd2xx0.20.0tar.gz
$ sudo cp *.h /usr/local/include/
$ sudo cp libftd2xx.so.0.20.0 /usr/local/lib/
$ cd /usr/local/lib/
$ sudo ln -s libftd2xx.so.0.20.0 libftd2xx.so
$ sudo ln -s libftd2xx.so.0.20.0 libftd2xx.so.0
$ cd /usr/lib/
$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/libftd2xx.so.0.20.0libftd2xx.so.0
$ sudo mount -a
```

-I am not able to figure out the issue, I only know this details. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance